# Matlab implement gaussian process

Tags: matlab

I want to implement the following gaussian process in Matlab. So far i tried normpdf and normrnd but the results are not what i was expecting. `B` is an `NxN` matrix and the expected result for en is a Nx1 vector. Using both methods I get an `NxN` matrix.

Any suggestions?

[image: gaussian process]

Comment: Mh, this looks weird. If you use a matrix as sigma, you should be dealing with a multivariate distribution, and you should receive a matrix back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
% Number of samples for each variable:
k = 100;

% Your parameters:
mu = [0; 0]; % Vector of Means (0 in your case)
cov = [3 1; 1 3]; % Covariance Matrix (your B)

% Draw the samples...
s = mvnrnd(mu,cov,k);
```

If you want to perform the same calculation manually (by generating a sample of independent standard normal variables and then applying the appropriate transformation):

```
% Number of samples for each variable:
k = 100;

% Your parameters:
mu = [0 0]; % Vector of Means (0 in your case)
cov = [3 1; 1 3]; % Covariance Matrix (your B)

% Draw the samples...
s_ind = randn(k,size(cov,1));
s = repmat(mu,k,1) + (chol(cov) * ind_s);
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation page for [`randn`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) shows the following example for generating samples from a bivariate normal distribution:

```
mu = [1 2];
sigma = [1 0.5; 0.5 2];
R = chol(sigma);
z = repmat(mu,10,1) + randn(10,2)*R
```

`mu` is the mean vector which you should set to a zero vector of appropriate size. `sigma` is the covariance matrix, `B^-1` in your example. The example above draws 10 samples, you can change this to however many you need. Also remember to change the dimension `2` to `N` in your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply